# What does the dollar symbol do in a back-ticked JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript, string, stringtemplate, dollar-sign

Why we use $ sign why we can't print it like second program?

```
let animals = 'elephants, eagles, owls, and tigers';
console.log(`${animals.slice(11,17)} and ${animals.slice(19,23)} are cool birds`);
```

2nd program

```
let ani = 'elephants, eagles, owls, and tigers';
console.log(ani.slice(11,17) + ' ' + 'and'+ ' '+ ani.slice(19,23) + ' ' + 'are cool birds');
```

Outputs of both programs are same:

> eagles and owls are cool birds
> eagles and owls are cool birds

Comment: In the first case you're (presumably) using a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) - in the second string concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

Both are valid. First one is called string template.